ZK customize datetime picker
how can I customize datetime picker,
I want to add << and >> buttons near < and >. Currently < and > buttons shows previous or next month calendar.
I want newly added buttons show next year, For example, current day 10.06.2024, when I click to next button it shows 10.07.2024, and I want to add >> button and onclick into it it should show 10.06.2025. Any idea?
ZK version 9.6 Input Date and Time Picker
zkoss.org/zkdemo/input/date_and_time_picker - this is what I use for the project it has previous and next month calendar buttons reflected on < and > on top the calendar popup I want to add buttons for previous and next year

The datebox component in ZK already has a way to switch years from the control.
If you click on the month name, the datebox will go to "month" selection. (select from Jan to Dec). In that state, clicking the left or right arrow will move to next / previous year.
If you click on the year number, you will go to year selection date, which works the same, but allows you to see the decade (10 years), then another click allows you to switch centuries (100 years).
Now, I know that's not exactly the behavior you are asking about. And ZK CAN be customized.
To make that kind of change, I'd recommend starting here:
How to build a custom mold (required to add elements to an existing control) https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZKClient-sideReference/Customization/Custom_Mold
How to customize a widget class https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZKClient-sideReference/GeneralControl/WidgetCustomization
And lastly, even though the change you want to make is on Datebox, the Datebox component itself contains a different widget called "calendar", which is the one showing the buttons you mentioned. Here's the calendar mold and widget class for ZK 9.6.5:
https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/v9.6.5/zul/src/archive/web/js/zul/db/Calendar.js https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/v9.6.5/zul/src/archive/web/js/zul/db/mold/calendar.js

I was able to figure out UI to add buttons for annual prev and next listing. But I have a hard time to activating them.
if (view == 'day') {
out.push('');
out.push('');
